# Go: Write to a file with windows-1252 encoding

Tags: character-encoding, go

Is it possible to write to a file in Go with a specific encoding like windows-1252 for instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to use a library to convert between encodings:

https://code.google.com/p/go-charset/

The library allows you to convert strings to and from encodings like `windows-1252`.

Comment: Worked great. Quick example: http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go-charset/charset#example-NewWriter

Answer (score 2):

Project [go.text](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.text/encoding) provides utilities for this precise case, with a Windows-1252 [charmap](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.text/encoding/charmap) defined.